# How does one open Tera Term using a Python script?

Tags: python, shell, teraterm

When trying to open Tera Term using a Python script, I receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           shell.Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe")
>         File "", line 2, in run
>       com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024894), None)

I used this as the following commands in Python shell to recreate the error message:

```
import os
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\teraterm\\ttermpro.exe")
```

Could anyone clarify what this error means and how I can proceed to solving it? There are a few posts on this, however they remain unanswered.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use `WScript.Shell`? What's wrong with `subprocess.call("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\teraterm\\ttermpro.exe")`?

Comment: Yes, I will be executing more commands using the same script.

Comment: Your problem is that your path has un-escaped spaces you need to use `'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\teraterm\\ttermpro.exe"'`